# How to get a user by Id and delete it after from firebase auth database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I want to add a feature in my app that allows the admin account to delete firebase user accounts from inside the app. I have the user Id that I want to delete stored in a String but can't get the user record from the firebase auth database using the Id.
The `getUser()` method stays in red and android studio shows a note :
Cannot resolve method `getUser(java.lang.String)`.

I already tried searching on the net for previous similar problems but they were all trying to delete the connected user and not a specific user of a given ID

```java
        // getIntent() is a method from the started activity
        Intent myIntent = getIntent(); // gets the previously created intent
        final String UserId = myIntent.getStringExtra("uid"); // will return "User Id"
        final Button btnDelete = findViewById(R.id.deleteaccount);
        final FirebaseUser userToDelete = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUser(UserId);
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                userToDelete.delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            Toast.makeText(TAG, "Account deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                            Toast.makeText(TAG, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        });
```

I want to achieve one goal: Being able to delete a user with a given Id.

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase web and mobile client libraries don't support the ability to get and delete user accounts, as that would pose a security risk.  The only way to programmatically [manage user accounts](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) is using the [Firebase Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) to on a backend you control.